# How to add context querying an external model to another model's template on Wagtail CMS

Tags: html, django, wagtail

I have the usual home.HomePage() model set up by wagtail by default and this is what it contains:

```
class HomePage(Page):
advertised_lowest_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=20,)
season_year = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
season_statement = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="THIS MUST BE IN 'h2' TAG! To avoid frontend"
                                                                  " display irregularities, you must use the"
                                                                  " H2 tag",
                                 features=['bold', 'italic', 'hr', 'link', 'document-link', 'embed', 'underline',
                                           'strike-through', 'h2', 'h3'],
                                 )
premium_topic = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='Premium Products text', max_length=80)
premium_sub_topic = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='Premium Products Sub-topic text',
                                     max_length=80)
article_section_topic = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=80)

def get_context(self, request):
    context = super().get_context(request)
    context['home_page'] = HomePage.objects.live().all()

    def carousel_products():
        carousel_items_list = []
        for carousel_item in AdministratorProducts.objects.all():
            carousel_items_list.append(carousel_item.is_carousel())
            return carousel_items_list

    context['carousel_1'] = carousel_products()[0]

    return context

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('advertised_lowest_price'),
    FieldPanel('season_year'),
    FieldPanel('season_statement'),
    FieldPanel('premium_topic'),
    FieldPanel('premium_sub_topic'),
    FieldPanel('article_section_topic'),
]

template = 'home/index.html'

def __str__(self):
    return self.season_statement
```

That said,I also have a Carousel mode that serves as a housing for other products that would be on the carousel on the index page > `index.html`.

This is the model for the Carousel:

```
class ImageCarousel(Page):
carousel_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='ART!')
date_time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='Date product was added to Carousel.')

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Images on the Carousel'

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('carousel_name'),
]

template = 'home/index.html'
```

As you might have noticed, `ImageCarousel` also writes to the same template as `HomePage` which is `index.html`.

At the same time, I have another model from another app that has `ImageCarousel` as a `ForeignKey`. Here is the model located at `'ixorabloom_administrator_products/models.py'`:

```
class AdministratorProducts(Page):
administrator_product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
administrator_product_bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
administrator_product_primary_genre = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=ART_GENRES, null=True, blank=True)
administrator_product_secondary_genre = models.TextField(help_text='Comma (,) separated list of secondary art '
                                                                   'genres',
                                                         null=True,
                                                         blank=True)
administrator_product_carousel = models.ForeignKey("home.ImageCarousel",
                                                   null=True,
                                                   blank=True,
                                                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
administrator_product_carousel_year = models.PositiveIntegerField(help_text="Year to be displayed if this product"
                                                                            " is on the carousel",
                                                                  null=True,
                                                                  blank=True)
administrator_product_date_of_creation = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='Date product was made')
administrator_product_website_link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='External website where this'
                                                                                      'product can be found or'
                                                                                      'bought.')
administrator_product_email_address = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='External Mailing site'
                                                                                         'where this product can be'
                                                                                         'ordered.')
administrator_product_picture = models.ForeignKey("wagtailimages.Image",
                                                  null=True,
                                                  blank=True,
                                                  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
administrator_product_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('administrator_product_name'),
    FieldPanel('administrator_product_bio'),
    FieldPanel('administrator_product_primary_genre'),
    FieldPanel('administrator_product_secondary_genre'),
    FieldPanel('administrator_product_carousel'),
    FieldPanel('administrator_product_carousel_year'),
    FieldPanel('administrator_product_website_link'),
    FieldPanel('administrator_product_email_address'),
    ImageChooserPanel('administrator_product_picture'),
    FieldPanel('administrator_product_price'),
    FieldPanel('administrator_product_date_of_creation'),
]

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Administrator Art Products'

def __str__(self):
    return self.administrator_product_name

def is_carousel(self):
    if self.administrator_product_carousel:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Looking back at `HomePage`, there is a `get_context()` method there. This method actually does a loop to gather products (from the administrator) that have a `ForeignKey` relationship with `ImageCarousel`. Here is the method:

```
    def get_context(self, request):
    context = super().get_context(request)
    context['home_page'] = HomePage.objects.live().all()

    def carousel_products():
        carousel_items_list = []
        for carousel_item in AdministratorProducts.objects.all():
            carousel_items_list.append(carousel_item.is_carousel())
            return carousel_items_list

    context['carousel_1'] = carousel_products()[0]

    return context
```

**You can also find this in ** `HomePage().get_context()`.

Here is the problem. The context does not work on the front-end. I have tested the performance of the `carousel_products()` function with `python manage.py shell` and it gets the work done. The issue here is that it isn't showing on the webpage powered by the template: `'home/index.html'`.

Here is the section of `'home/index.html'` That makes use of the newly added context:

```
            {% if carousel_1 %}
        <div class="hs-item">
            <div class="hs-left"><img src="{{ carousel_1.administrator_product_picture.url }}" alt=""></div>
            <div class="hs-right">
                <div class="hs-content">
                    <div class="price">from ₦{{ carousel_1.administrator_product_price }}</div>
                    <h2 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                        <span>{{ carousel_1.administrator_product_carousel_year }}</span>
                        <br>
                    </h2>
                    <a href="" class="site-btn">Shop NOW!</a>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can I please also get a solution to this problem? Anything that I've not added to the question, please let me know and I will provide the required data. 
**I also have terribly hard times with context on Wagtail CMS. I really wish someone could clearly explain their template design and use system. My implementations have all been from the Wagtail documentation. Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is in the `HomePage()` model. Precisely, `get_context().carousel_products()`. This is the correction to `carousel_products()`.

```
        def carousel_products():
            carousel_items_list = []
            for carousel_item in AdministratorProducts.objects.all():
                if carousel_item.is_carousel():
                    carousel_items_list.append(carousel_item)
                return carousel_items_list
```

The problem with the original code was that the for loop was querying each product from `AdministratorProducts` (i.e `AdministratorProducts.objects.all()`) and checking if each product was a carousel item. What is returned is either `True` or `False`.

In the original code, what was being appended to the `carousel_items_list` was the returned value of that check (i.e `True` or `False`) and not the product or the product's name.

My solution fixes that error in judgment about the performance of the function. Now the function returns the correct data and the templates load the required data.